# Open EDX - LMS : Unable to send verification email

Tags: django, python-2.7, openedx

I have a server setup for python 2.7. I have followed the below link for open edx setup and configuration.
[Click here](https://github.com/regisb/openedx-install)

After doing a lot of stuff, I have successfully run CMS and LMS on different domains. Everything is working except emails. When I registered from LMS, I didn't found verification mail. Because of that, I am not able to login to LMS system.

- I have added SMTP details in lms.env.json
- I have also replaced the console by smtp in aws.py, common.py
- I have also restarted all the services after doing this but none worked for 
  me.

Please help me to get out of this.

Comment: Did you check the logs?

Comment: Which logs do I need to check??

Comment: Where can I find the logs??

Comment: edx logs, and server mail queue. and ports.

Comment: I have a logs folder at root but its empty.

Comment: if its in AWS, you can not send email using port 25. If the port is blocked then you have to use another email service to send emails.
Did you check "mail queue"